# Session variables inside iframe 3rd part on safari doesnt work

Tags: variables, session, iis, model-view-controller, safari

My sites when used in iframes stop working in Safari browsers because session variables stop working, in IE or Chrome they still work.

Comment: Have you ever tried to add  response header "P3P", "CP=CAO PSA OUR"  to the web site?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you had to configure IIS as follows:

[image: Access Session State]

[image: Configure Session State]

If you have ajax calls, remove the back slash from url "\Compra"

[image]